# Using Google Sheer's Filter option on 2 columns where one is date?

Tags: google-sheets, filter

I have 2 columns one with letters A,B,C and other one with number 1,2,3. If I want to only see those letters whose corresponding numbers are less than 3, I would `=filter(O39:O41,P39:P41<3)`. It works.

[image]

If I change second column to dates, this breaks. `=filter(O39:O41,P39:P41<1/3)` tells me `No matches are found in FILTER evaluation.`

[image]

Please help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap it up in `date` or use something relative to `date` like `=filter(range, date_range< TODAY(), date_range> TODAY()-50)`